# Cross validation in random forest using anaconda

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, data-analysis, cross-validation

I'm using the titanic data set to predict if a passenger survived or not using random forest. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import cross_validation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\kabala\\Downloads\\Titanic.csv")
data.isnull().any()
data["Age"]=data1["Age"].fillna(data1["Age"].median())
data["PClass"]=data["PClass"].fillna("3rd")
data["PClass"].isnull().any()
data1.isnull().any()
pd.get_dummies(data.Sex)
# choosing the predictive variables 
x=data[["PClass","Age","Sex"]]
# the target variable is y 
y=data["Survived"]
modelrandom=RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3)
modelrandom=cross_validation.cross_val_score(modelrandom,x,y,cv=5)
```

But, I keep on getting this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'female'
```

and I don't understand what is the problem because I changed the Sex feature to a dummy

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

`pd.get_dummies` returns a data frame, and does not do the operation in place.  Therefore you really are sending a sting with the `sex` column.

So you would need something like `X = pd.get_dummies(data[['Sex','PClass','Age']], columns=['Sex','PClass'])` and this should fix your problem.  I think `PClass` will also be a string column you need to use dummy variables, as you have it filling `'3rd'`.

There are still some more places where you call `data.isnull().any()` that is not doing anything to the underlying dataframe.  I left those as they were, but just FYI they may not be doing what you intended.

Full code would be:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import cross_validation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\kabala\\Downloads\\Titanic.csv")
data.isnull().any()   <-----Beware this is not doing anything to the data
data["Age"]=data1["Age"].fillna(data1["Age"].median())
data["PClass"]=data["PClass"].fillna("3rd")
data["PClass"].isnull().any()  <-----Beware this is not doing anything to the data
data1.isnull().any() <-----Beware this is not doing anything to the data

#********Fix for your code*******
X = pd.get_dummies(data[['Sex','PClass','Age']], columns=['Sex','PClass'])

# choosing the predictive variables 
# x=data[["PClass","Age","Sex"]]
# the target variable is y 
y=data["Survived"]
modelrandom=RandomForestClassifier(max_depth=3)
modelrandom=cross_validation.cross_val_score(modelrandom,x,y,cv=5)
```